# Drupal form validation functions

Tags: drupal, forms, validation, drupal-fapi

Is there anyway say Drupal to validate form elements like email fields, passwords, numeric fields validate automatically lets say bind a system validator

`$form['email] = array(
   '#title' => t('Email'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#validate_as' => array('email', ...),
   ...
);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rimian is both correct and wrong.

The good thing as Rimian points out, is that you can attach any validation function to your form fields using the `#element_validate`.

However I'm not aware of a set of form api validation functions you can call to test most common things like, if the value is:

- a int
- a positive int
- a valid date (such a function exists in the date module though)
- a email-address (you can use [`valid_email_address`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/valid_email_address/6) to check the email, but you need a function to raise validation error)

So while you can do this, it's a bit more work than you were hoping for, as you will need to create these validation functions yourself. But once you have done this, you can reuse them with `#element_validate`.

The use of `#element_validate` is mostly centered around complex validation fx date validation, location validation and such, as it requires some work to create these validation functions. Most of the time, you don't need to validate that many numbers etc (which you quite easily could do within a normal validation function using a loop). So I'm not sure how much this will be of help to you, but it's definitely a possibility.

Answer (score 6):

To validate a numeric field in Drupal use:

```
'#element_validate' => array('element_validate_number')
```

No need to create a custom validation function.
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/element_validate_number/7

Answer (score 1):

Yep!

Though I have not experimented with it much.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#element_validate

```
$form = array(  
  '#type' => 'fieldset',  
  '#title' => t('Input format'),  
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,  
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,  
  '#weight' => $weight,  
  '#element_validate' => array('filter_form_validate'),  
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Form API Validation module does exactly what you request: http://drupal.org/project/fapi_validation

For client-side validation there is also http://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation (which can use rules provided by Form API Validation).